# Parsing pdf metadata with pdfminer for data type pdfobject

Tags: pdf, metadata, pdfminer, pdfobject

I have encountered a field in my pdf metadata which is a dict of pdfobjref and when I resolve it , it is a object of pdfstream I am not sure how do I decode to get the necessary info. To be honest I don't know what information it could provide either. Can anyone guide me?

Val= resolve_all(Val)

Comment: Reading the [PDF Reference](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.7old.pdf) might help you out.


Then, you can use the Layout Analysis Algorithm from [pdfminer.six](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/extract_pages.html) to extract objects in a human-readable way.

Comment: You can [use `pypdf` to read metadata](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/metadata.html#reading-metadata)